# Gitlab can't clone on server, but can clone on client

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitlab, ubuntu-16.04

**Additional details:**

- Project is private
- server user ssh key added to authorized_keys and ssh also added to user's gitlab ssh setting

I have an ubuntu 16.04 server with git and gitlab installed in it. I have managed to set it up and get it running. I even managed to do normal git operations on my client machines (windows). But when I try to clone (git clone git@192.168.0.3:root/project.git) a repo from the server on to the server's /var/www/html directory it shows this error:

fatal: 'root/project.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

**Note:** I have cloned this same project with my client machines and it works fine

**Update:** I was able to clone a repo but via HTTP

Does anybody have any idea on how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Have you compared the versions of the various git packages you are using? Also, how did you create the `project.git` file? Was it copied from windows, or created by the local git on the server? Can you create a local repo and clone that?

Comment: 1. The project.git file was created by gitlab
2. Yes the project was created on windows and pushed to the server
3. I can't even push to a created repo 
sorry new to this git thing

Comment: Could you please provide the permissions of `/var/www`?

Comment: "Update: I was able to clone a repo but via HTTP" well, how did you try to clone it in the first place then? This question lacks all information that's needed do debug this.

Comment: On the server, do a `ssh -T git@192.168.0.3`: do you see `Welcome on GitLab, userX`? If not, that would explain the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is not git but your permssions on Ubuntu**

> Update: I was able to clone a repo but via HTTP

There you go. The gitlab server is supposed to be accessed via HTTP(S), because usually you don't clone from a repository that is located on the same computer.

To prevent other users or apps from accessing/manipulating data in the repositories, only the gitlab server has access to its files.

Although this is not recommended (because it is against linux' permission philosophy where each server has got its own user account) you can still give yourself permissions.

**Variant 1 (less invasive)**
Either add yourself to the group under which the gitlab server is running

```
sudo usermod -a -G gitlab paul
```

and ensure the owner group does at least have reading permissions on the directory

```
sudo chown g+r /var/www/path/to/the/repo
```

*and on the files (update)*

```
sudo chown -R g+r /var/www/path/to/the/repo
```

**Variant 2 (dirty, simple hack)**

If you can ensure nobody else with an account on your computer wants to access (private) repositories on gitlab, you can give everyone read permissions:

```
sudo chown o+r /var/www/path/to/repo
```

The operating system will then allow you to access the folder and git will be able to clone from the local path.

**However it's a good practice to use systems as they were thought to use.** If you clone using the local path gitlab won't notice this and, for example, will not adjust the statistics or run web hooks.

Comment: "The gitlab server is supposed to be accessed via HTTP(S), because usually you don't clone from a repository that is located on the same computer." - Thank you for enlightening me on this. It all makes sense to me now. I tried variant 1: and added myself to the git group(there was no gitlab group) still the same result

Comment: No problem, yes maybe you know that gitlab offers the hosting of repositories (just like GitHub, Bitbucket, etc.) The difference between using their services and what you do is that you want to host the code your own server and normally you don't work directly on your server but rather clone from it on other computers. May I ask you to update your question and insert the output of `ls -l /var/www/path/to/repo` so I can see the permissions?

Comment: I forgot to mention you should set the permissions on all files in that directory and not just on the directory itself. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Also please show us what command you invoke to clone the repository on the same computer. Do you know that you have to provide the full path to the repository? I guess there are several solutions but you need to provide some more information on your setup ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is about authentication: if the user on the server (doing the clone) is not properly authenticated to GitLab (through username/password or ssh key), it won't have the right to access the repo and you will get the generic error message.

Check the permission level associated to the GitLab project: unless it is declared as public (no authentication required), you would need to add the server user to the project member list.

Another workaround would be to clone the bare repo stored on the GitLab server directly (in [`/home/git/repositories/` by default](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/4784d7896d755f282c6c629d236a4583ae45842b/config/gitlab.yml.example#L458-L466)), since you are on the GitLab server.